# Some direction with proving a set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an assignment requiring me to prove whether various sets are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$. One I am struggling with is:

$$ W = \{ (u+v+2w, -v-w, v+w) | u, v, w \in \mathbb{R} \}$$

Obviously proving a subset is a subspace involves:

1. $ 0 \in W$
2. Closure under vector addition
3. Closure under scalar multiplication

And for other examples such as $W = \{(x,y,x) | x+y-z = 0\} $
I can prove that quite easily.

However I dont really have an idea how to progress with the set above?
I considered a vector $v = (x,y,z)$ where
$$x = u+v+2w$$
$$y = -v-w$$
$$z=v+w$$

and would try to prove the 3 requirements somehow? But I honestly do not have a clue how to even begin.

I am not necessarily asking for a full solution, I believe with some guidance as to how to look at this problem I can probably solve it myself.

Thank you!

Comment: $$(u+v+2w,−v−w,v+w)=u(1,0,0)+v(1,-1,1)+w(2,-1,1)$$ Your set $W$ is just the span of three vectors. Any span is a subspace, (almost?) by definition.

Comment: (These three vectors are linearly dependent, as $(1,0,0)+(1,-1,1)-(2,-1,1)=0$, but that doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider scalar $a$ and vectors $(u_1+v_1+2w_1,-v_1-w_1,v_1+w_1)$ and $(u_2+v_2+2w_2,-v_2-w_2,v_2+w_2)$ in $W$. You need to show that:

1. There exists $(u_1,v_1,w_1) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(u_1+v_1+2w_1,-v_1-w_1,v_1+w_1)=(0,0,0)$.
2. $(u_1+v_1+2w_1,-v_1-w_1,v_1+w_1)+(u_2+v_2+2w_2,-v_2-w_2,v_2+w_2) \in W$. That is, sum the two vectors and show that they take the same format. In other words, find $(u_3,v_3,w_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of $v_1,v_2,u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2$ such that $(u_1+v_1+2w_1,-v_1-w_1,v_1+w_1)+(u_2+v_2+2w_2,-v_2-w_2,v_2+w_2) =(u_3+v_3+2w_3,-v_3-w_3,v_3+w_3)$.
3. Similarly show that $a(u_1+v_1+2w_1,-v_1-w_1,v_1+w_1)\in W$ by showing the resulting vector takes the same format.